# If $(PQ - I)$ is invertible, verify $(QP - I)$ is invertible with inverse:$ -I + Q(PQ-I)^{-1}P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, inverse

Let P,Q be *n* x *n* matrices. Suppose that (PQ - I) is invertible. Verify that (QP - I) is also invertible with the following inverse:

$$
(QP-I)^{-1} = -I + Q(PQ-I)^{-1}P
$$

I have some intuition for why it's true, namely $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$ but beyond that I'm not sure why this is the case.

Comment: Just multiply them directly and show you get the identity.

Comment: Hint for the first part: Remember AB and BA always have the same eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=-I+Q(PQ-I)^{-1}P$. Then
$$ (QP-I)A = I-QP +(QP-I)Q(PQ-I)^{-1}P $$
It suffices to show that the the second two terms cancel.
$$ (QP-I)Q(PQ-I)^{-1}P = (QPQ-Q)(PQ-I)^{-1}P = Q(PQ-I)(PQ-I)^{-1}P = QP, $$
and the result follows since if a square matrix has a one-sided inverse, the same matrix is a two-sided inverse for it.

Comment: Can you get (QP-I)^-1 given (PQ - I) is invertible?

Comment: I suspect to derive this would essentially just reverse the verification I've given, unfortunately: I think it's one of those weird results, like the [resolvent identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_formalism#Resolvent_identity), that just happen to come out. I'd love to be proven wrong, though!